# Tag video por createelement

Tags: javascript, html5-video

Estou criando uma página inteira pelo método Document.createElement(), só que estou enfrentando um problema em criar uma tag vídeo. Ele cria o elemento mas não reproduz o vídeo, gostaria de saber se a tag vídeo funciona com o createElement.

```
    var table = document.createElement("TABLE");
    table.setAttribute("align","center");
    var trplay = document.createElement("TR");
    var tdplay = document.createElement("TD");
    var player = document.createElement("VIDEO");
    player.setAttribute("width","502");
    player.setAttribute("height","360");
    player.setAttribute("id","Video1");
    var source = document.createElement("SOURCE");
    source.setAttribute("scr","video1.webm");
    source.setAttribute("type","video/webm");
```

ele cria o seguinte código:

```
<table align="center">
 <tr>
  <td>
   <video width="502" height="360" id="Video1">
    <source scr="video1.webm" type="video/webm">
   </video>
  </td>
 </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tenta criar o elemento da seguinte forma:

```
var player = document.createElement('video');
player.src = 'video1.webm';
player.autoPlay = true;
```

Assim ele vai setar a reprodução automaticamente. Teu problema também pode estar vinculado ao formato do video, que você pode verificar assim:

```
if (player.canPlayType('video/webm').length > 0) {
    /* Aqui o formato é suportado */
}
```

Acredito que assim vai funcionar.